# Pryrc does not seem to be loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I just started a new project with RAils 4.2 on ruby 2.1.2. In the Gemfile, it clearly states that pry-byebug is included,  and in my ~/.pryrc file I have the following

```
puts "HELLO!!"
if defined?(Rails) && Rails.env
  extend Rails::ConsoleMethods
end


require 'hirb'
Hirb.enable
```

When I do

```
$ rails c
```

I don't see "hellO' being printed and I don't get Hirb's pretty format

Any chance someone can tell me where should I start looking where the error might be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to include `gem 'pry-rails'` in my Gemfile, and not within any groups.